# calling a method in a class with listview

Tags: android, listactivity

I am new to android coding and was making a project with ListView.  I wrote a program that displays information in a text file in a listview. Right now I have my main file extending ListActivity and everything works.  The main file is calling another class

> fileop.ReadFileAsList("Installed_packages.txt");

which reads each line of the text file.  What I want is to make this a method in a class called FileOperations and do exactly what it is doing now, but my main class in my other project Extends Activity and I do not know how to "call" Extend Listactivity AND Activity.  I don't think this can be done in Java probably for good reason.  Could anyone show me how I would/should refactor it? Main file followed by code below:

Bottom line I am trying to make this a method in fileop and move fileop to a new project where the main extends Activity and not ListActivity.

```
 MAIN:

package com.example.hellolistview;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HelloListViewActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, file));  

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text      
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
        });
    }
    static FileOperations fileop= new FileOperations();
    static final String[] file =fileop.ReadFileAsList("Installed_packages.txt");
    }
```

---

```
package com.example.hellolistview;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

public class FileOperations {

    public String[] ReadFileAsList(String fileName){        
        try{
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Nullwall/" + fileName);
            FileInputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream(f);
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    fileIS));
            StringBuilder DbLines = new StringBuilder(); 
            String line = buf.readLine();
            while (buf.readLine() != null)
                {
                DbLines.append(line);
                DbLines.append("\r\n");
                }
            String[] ListItems = DbLines.toString().split("\r\n");

            return ListItems;
            }


 catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("FileOp_ReadFileAsList","File Not Found in ReadFileAsList()");

}
 catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("FileOp_ReadFileAsList","IOException in ReadFileAsList()");
    }
        Log.e("FileOp_ReadFileAsList","Probably an Error in ReadFileAsList()");
        return null;

}
}
```

---

EDIT:

My new Main file (Where I want to go):

```
package com.IPR2.viewlog;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class Main extends Activity {
    private TextView tv;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FileOperations fileOperations = new FileOperations();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        //fileOperations.ClearFile("Installed_packages.txt");
        ApplicationOperations.ListAllInstalledApplications(getApplicationContext());
        ReadFileAsList("Installed_packages.txt"); <--What Im trying to be able to do.  It wont let me

    }
    public String[] ReadFileAsList(String fileName){

}
```

Comment: it doesn't matter you just copy that FileOperations.java file to your new project change the package name and use it I would also make this method like `public static String[] ReadFileAsList(...)` like it's a helper method. and call it like FileOperations.ReadFileAsList(....) from a required class.

Comment: My main file (HelloListViewActivity.java) extends ListActivity and needs to extend ListActivity because I get the following error:

`setListAdapter and getListView() are undefined.`  How Do I define them?

In my "main" file (Main.java) all I want to do is call FileOperations.ReadFileasList("Installed_packages.txt"); and have it execute as it does now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling the `ReadFileAsList()` method before `onCreate()`.
this is not allowed.
change to the following:

```
public class HelloListViewActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    static FileOperations fileop=null;
    static final String[] file=null; 


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.fileop = new FileOperations();
        this.file = fileop.ReadFileAsList("Installed_packages.txt");

   setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, this.file));

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
        });
    }

    }
```

Comment: I added my new main file and what I want to be able to do above. Does this help understand what I am trying to do?

Comment: LOL. you have FileOperations fileOperations = new FileOperations(); and use your  fileOperations.ReadFileAsList("Installed_packages.txt"); there

Comment: Ahh sorry that was me copying wrong.  Where Do I set my listView?  Obviously It wont work without 

`Code`

Comment: as I said you copy that file to your new project. change it's package name and import it in your new Activity and that's about it. copy that file to your package com.IPR2.viewlog; or any package inside it like package com.IPR2.viewlog.util; (create if beforehand). and copy that file inside it import in your activity and use it.

Comment: `setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, file)); 
 
        ListView lv = getListView(); 
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true); 
 
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                        int position, long id) { 
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text`

Comment: what does "import it in your new activity" mean

Comment: it means import it! like `import com.IPR2.viewlog.utils.FileOperations;` if you have this package. if you don't have just copy that file into your new activity's folder and use it as usual. edit your new activity. show me how it looks like.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7694/discussion-between-peterl-and-sergey-benner)